# $\text{SU}(N)$ is path-connected

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Why is $\text{SU}(N)$ path-connected? I want to construct a path, maybe via induction and finding a path which rotates the last column vector to the basis
vector $e_N$.

Can somebody make this more precise? How can a path be constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need the following theorem.

> **Theorem:**  Every unitary matrix has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, with eigenvalues having absolute value 1.

Therefore any matrix $A\in SU(N)$ can be written as $A=U\Lambda U^{-1}$ where

$$\Lambda=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
e^{i\theta_1}& &0 \\
 &\ddots& \\
0& &e^{i\theta_N}
\end{array}\right)$$

with $\sum \theta_i=0$. Now the map $f\colon [0,1]\to SU(N), t\mapsto U\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
e^{i\theta_1t}& &0 \\
 &\ddots& \\
0& &e^{i\theta_Nt}
\end{array}\right)U^{-1}$ constructs a path in $SU(N)$ with endpoints $f(0)=I$ and $f(1)=A$.