# Show the special unitary group is connected

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, analysis

Let $SU(n)$ be the group of $n \times n $special unitary complex matrices. Show that $SU(n)$ is connected.

Here are some thoughts:

By definition $SU(n) = \{ A \in GL(n): A^*A=I=AA^*, det (A)=I \}$.

I know that $det: SU(n) \rightarrow \{1\}$ is a continuous surjective map.

I also know that continuous image of a connected set is connected. But in this case it's not really helping.

I showed that the group  $SU(n)$ is compact.

But from here I'm not sure how to proceed to show connectedness.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You have to find a way to connect an arbitrary $A\in SU(n)$ to the identity. Why don't you start by observing that $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508865/textsun-is-path-connected?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

First observation is that it is enough to show that $U(n)$ is connected (a unitary path between two special unitary matrices can obviously be deformed to lie in $SU(n)$). To show that $U(n)$ is connected, use the [Cayley Transform.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cayley_transform)

Answer (score 2):

Another argument to show $SU(n)$ is connected is to show every element is path-connected to an element of the subgroup $SU(n-1)$ using the fact the action $SU(n)\curvearrowright S^{2n-1}\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ is transitive (for $n>1$). This argument can be adapted for $SO(n)$ and $Sp(n)$ as well.

Yet another argument is involves the exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak{su}(n)\to SU(n)$. You can restrict it to a closed ball of a large enough radius and argue it's still surjective (elements of $U(n)$ are unitarily diagonalizable). The continuous image of a connected set is connected.

Comment: The second argument is actually quite similar (and, I think closely related) to the Cayley transform argument.....)